# Build directory structure from file list with windows components and scripting tools

Tags: powershell

I need some help with building of directory structure from the list of files. It should be some graphic view (html or windows form), support unicode and be quick. File list is not exact files/directories structure, just some random files in some random folders.

Let's say I have a file where file names listed:

- \\srv1\ndisk\finance\1.xtx
- \\srv1\ndisk\finance\2.xtx
- \\srv1\ndisk\bookkeepers\3.xtx
- \\srv1\ndisk\bookkeepers\4.xtx
- \\srv1\ndisk\ceo\5.xtx

And I want to get something like this:

```
-srv1
   -ndisk
      -finance
          1.xtx
          2.xtx
      -bookkeepers
          3.xtx
          4.xtx
      -ceo
          5.xtx
```

I'm not developer actually, so I should rely on scripting languages, like powershell, vbs and so on. Maybe there are some components that can just build this tree from file list that I have?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. That being said, it is expect that you show what you have done or tried before posting. This gives us something to build on. As of now this reads like a code writing request which is off topic for SO. Break your question into its parts and search individually for solutions to those problems. Then, if you are still having issues, please [edit] your question showing your work so we can better help you and the community.

Comment: Well, what do you expect me to write I did before? I simply do not know and I even do not know what to ask from google? I asked for component name that can accept file names as arguments, which code should I show you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `tree` commandline instruction, from within a standard windows commandline prompt. E.g.

```
TREE /F C:\Temp
```

Comment: yeah... that wont work here since the op is trying to build this from a static list of files without a connection to an existing directory structure.

Comment: I do not have any folder to build a structure from. Just a file with a list of files from different folders and directories